# Script code of line not working with a method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, registerstartupscript

I have a script in my **.aspx** page (HTML Markup):

```
<div id="alert">
    <asp:Label ID="lblAlert" style="font-size: xx-large" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
<!-- /.alert -->

<script>

    function AutoHideAlert(v) {
        var al = document.getElementById('<%=lblAlert.ClientID%>');

        al.innerText = v;

        $("#alert").fadeTo(3500, 500).slideUp(1500, function () {
            $("#alert").slideUp(500);
        });
    }

</script>
```

I'm calling `AutoHideAlert(v)` function in **aspx.cs** file (Code-Behind) using `RegisterStartupScript` and I have added `RegisterStartupScript` in `ShowMessage` method:

```
private void ShowMessage(string msg)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), null, "AutoHideAlert('"+msg+"');", true);
}
```

The problem is when I call `ShowMessage` method which contains script code line its not working. But when I run script code line then its working; the question is why its not running with `ShowMessage`?

**Edit 1:** From @M4N's comment, I have tried it by setting third parameter as `"Alert Message"` but it still not working.

```
private void ShowMessage(string msg)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Alert Message", "AutoHideAlert('"+msg+"');", true);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `key` parameter (3rd parameter) to some value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` generates script before the script with method was generated. As JS executed at the moment browser reads it, so at the moment of execution `AutoHideAlert` if not existed yet
try to use `$(document).ready` is you have JQuery

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Alert Message",
     "$(document).ready(function(){ AutoHideAlert('"+msg+"'); }", true);
```

Or `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'` without JQuery

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Alert Message",
     "document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', 
                                function(){ AutoHideAlert('"+msg+"'); })", true);
```

Comment: how to use with method?

Comment: there are 2 usage examples with JQuery and without, Ido not know if you have JQuery that is why I give you both

Comment: are you getting any browser (developer tools) console error messages?

Comment: no I'm not getting any error but script is not running within method

Comment: add `debugger;` before `AutoHideAlert`, it will causes dev tools to start debug, in that moment check what was actually generated and what can you access from that point

Comment: Share also the HTML result (parts with JS) that were generated as a result of your operation

Comment: Result of `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` and if it is before or after code you've posted already